# Posting on server from android phone

Tags: php, android, latitude-longitude

Its been long and after a lot of research i couldnt get the solution for what i really want. I have made a GPS tracking app. now i want to post the coordinates which i get from the phone to my localhost server. And that too it post the coordinates every 5 mins. I made a server using WAMP.

PHP script

```
?php

echo 'Hello, world!';

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ric_db", $con);

$devid = $_POST["devid"];
$latitude = $_POST["latitude"];
$longitude = $_POST["longitude"];





$sql = "INSERT INTO  `ric_db`.`locations` (
`id` ,
`devid` ,
`latitude` ,
`longitude` ,
`service`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '$devid',  '$latitude',  '$longitude',  '$service'
);";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Java File

```
@Override 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{ 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

setContentView(R.layout.main); 



/* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */ 

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(); 



mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener); 



} 



/* Class My Location Listener */ 

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 

{ 
 Context context;
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 

{ 
StringBuilder sb = null;
   String result = null;
   InputStream is = null;

double latitude = loc.getLatitude(); 

    double longitude = loc.getLongitude(); 
   Toast.makeText(context, "Latitude:" +latitude + "Longitude:" +longitude, 5000).show();
  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     String Devid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();




//this is JSON part to put your information inside it
String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"Devid\":\""+Devid+"\",\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\"}}";

String url="http://localhost/mehul/store.php";


List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Devid", Devid));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Double.toString(latitude) )); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", Double.toString(longitude))); 

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

HttpEntity http_entity = response.getEntity();

Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(http_entity.getContent()));
String res = br.readLine();
System.out.println(res);


}





public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Please some help me with this...

Comment: Please provide more details.  I can tell that you are trying to get the data into a mysql database on the server, but you haven't mentioned what errors you are running into or what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Also, are you using a data interchange format (json/xml) or just sending these as post/get fields embedded in the request?

Comment: You have not asked any question in your post.  Please ask a specific progeramming question.

Comment: Actually i am new to json so dont exactly know how to do it.. Can someone help me with it..The gps app is working fine just want to post it.. and what changes do i make in mt php

Comment: You don't need to specify the name of the database again in your MySQL query. Just the table name will do. And `$service` does not seem to be set. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, so use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape your user input.

Comment: can you help me with the code of php

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `localhost` in your url, use IP adress of server instead.
And your PHP script has bad start tag: `?php` instead of `<?php`

Please comment what errors do you get if this does not help...

Comment: how to get the ip address of server...?

Comment: in windows: open command prompt (`run>cmd`) and type `ipconfig` and you'll get your IP adress.
in Ubuntu: right-click on network applet and choose `connection information`